# The usage of "All clear"

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases

Based on Merriam-Webster: "all clear" means a signal that a danger has passed

I would like to use it for another purpose in the sentence:

> I have rejected him the moment he came **all clear** about his feelings
>   toward me.

Is my usage of the phrase proper?

Comment: Since you're referring to a thing that took place in the past ("the moment he **came** clean about his feelings") as the time of your rejecting, you cannot use the present perfect in your main clause. *I **rejected** him the moment he came clean...*, not **have rejected**.  If you want to make his coming clean the *starting point* of your ongoing rejecting then you can use the perfect with "ever since": *I have been rejecting his advances **ever since** the moment he came clean...*

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo - We have been taught that we should use the present perfect when an action happens in the past but has effect in the present. So, I somehow applied that on my sentence. However, I clearly see your point, and I think I have a few sentences that would perfectly work with the present perfect continuous + ever since. Thanks for shedding light on the tense issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, your use of *all clear* isn't proper.

Not only because that's not the meaning we would associate with *all clear* but also because there is *already* a common phrase that's used in the way you describe: **come clean**.

From Merriam-Webster's definition of [*come*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/come%20clean):

> *transitive verb*
>   **come clean**
>
> : to tell the whole story : CONFESS
>   // *came clean* about her crimes

In your example sentence, what people would already say is:

> I rejected him the moment he **came clean** about his feelings toward me.

Comment: This is exactly the phrase that I wanted to use, but remembered it as "all clear". Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

[All clear:](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/all-clear)

> If someone in authority gives you the all clear, they give you permission to continue with a plan or activity, usually after a problem has been sorted out.
>
> - *I was given the all clear by the doctor to resume playing*.

(Collins Dictionary)

You sentence makes an inappropriate  usage of “all clear”. You should probably say:

> I rejected him the moment he clearly showed his feelings toward me.